# SQL Statement for Oracle Reports Builder Break Group

Tags: sql, oracle, oraclereports

[Oracle Reports Builder Break Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcQPr.gif)

Can any one explain how the example break group could be translated into an equivalent SQL statement?

Since some of you are unable to view the image, below is an ASCII diagram of the example:

```
     ----
     |Q_1|
     ----
      |
      |
----------------
|G_DEPARTMENT_ID|
----------------
| DEPARTMENT_ID |
| JOB_ID        |
----------------     
      |
      |
---------------
|G_EMPLOYEE_ID|
---------------
| EMPLOYEE_ID |
| FIRST_NAME  |
| LAST_NAME   |
| SALARY      |
---------------
```

Comment: Type it out if you can. Images are not visible to many members and thus cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is an ordinary query:

```
select 
  -- fields that make G_DEPARTMENT_ID group
  department_id,
  job_id,
  -- fields that make G_EMPLOYEE_ID group
  employee_id,
  first_name,
  last_name,
  salary
from some_table
where ...
```

If you use Wizard to create a report (which is preferable way of doing it), it asks you what type of a report you want - that layout would be one of "Group" layouts (*above* or *left*, doesn't matter). Then you'd select which fields should belong to the "Group above" (department_id and job_id). Wizard will also create layout that supports such a model and everything will work just fine.

If you're doing it manually, no problem as far as Data Model Layout is concerned: by default, everything (all fields) will be in the same group. Then drag DEPARTMENT_ID out of existing group and put it in between QUERY and G_EMPLOYEE_ID group - it'll automatically create a new group. Then move JOB_ID in there.

However, creating a Paper Layout is much more difficult, as you'll have to create new frames, fields, take care that everything is correctly contained in appropriate frame etc. Even if you *know* what you're doing, it is not straightforward job; perhaps it is easier to delete existing layout and let Wizard create it from scratch.